# "No one's more queer than me" - What am I?

Tags: riddle

```
No one's more queer than me.

I can be a river, or a rain,
water pours from me.

Think I'm easy?
I'll burn your tongue.
```

**What am I?**

Comment: "It's raining Men!  Hallelujah!"

Comment: @Chowzen ...I should have seen that one coming...  Ironically, if that's what you're into, it may help you get the answer. (I'm generalising, sorry)

Comment: "No one's more queer... I'll burn..." Anyone else thinking of [Moriarty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz4aB00WzD8) a la *Sherlock*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going for:

> dance

because we have:

No one's more queer than me.

> queer=dirty, [Dirty Dancing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092890/) with Patrick Swayze

I can be a river, or a rain,
water pours from me.

> [Riverdance](http://riverdance.com), [Rain dance](http://www.indians.org/articles/rain-dance.html), [House of Dancing Water](http://www.thehouseofdancingwater.com/)

Think I'm easy?
I'll burn your tongue.

> Easy dancing (?) and [fire breathing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_performance) is part of dancing with fire

Comment: Correct! ...and yet somehow with almost none of my explanations! Queer was as in "queer as folk" and water pours was a tap (but yours is good), easy was "cake walk" and burn your tongue was "salsa"  +1

Comment: so folk dance, tap dance and easy=piece of cake. vg

Comment: Well a "Cake Walk" is both a dance and "an absurdly or surprisingly easy task"

Comment: Whoa!! I'm amazed after reading this answer, [take a bow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOoNOs8Ql28&list=PLFkMg1BXn_2OT3KDO6GsZlb7zCNcGzd7h&index=2) sir :D

Answer (score 4):

My guess is

> Twister or twisted.

No one's more queer than me.

> Twisted can mean weird or eccentric. Being "on the twist" is British slang for being dishonest.

I can be a river, or a rain,

> Twisted River is a book by John Irving. A twister is a kind of storm.

water pours from me.

> There's a kind of lawn sprinkler called a twister. The Webster definition for twister mentions waterspout.

Think I'm easy?
I'll burn your tongue.

> I think this is a reference to tongue twisters.

Comment: Nope.  Love the explanations though.  Especially the tongue one.  ...but actually, twist would've been another good clue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer :

> Cloud

because

**queer as me**

> they are strange(random) in shape.

**I can be a river,or a rain**

> It depends on the area where precipitation takes place, rain is normal, cloudburst can cause 'river like' situation.

**Water pours from me** = as explained above.

**Think I'm easy? I'll burn your tongue**

> It was actually difficult to decode this line, so here's what I understood. Clouds are taken for granted, even though they are one of the best part of nature, they come in different variety, form beautiful shapes, cause rains, etc. And when they cause lightening, everyone is scared, the electricity from the thundering is of several thousand volts, can kill in an instant or at least cause high degree burns, even to tongue.

Comment: Far thinking and well explained.  I like it!  ...It's not the answer I'm looking for.  Also you mistyped when you added your comments.

Comment: Thanks, and actually I'm using the mobile app of SE, it will take time to adjust to it :)

Comment: No bother.  I've tried to make the edit for you.

Answer (score 0):

No one's more queer than me.

> - Vapor

I can be a river, or a rain, 
water pours from me.

> - Vapor

Think I'm easy?
I'll burn your tongue.

> - Vapor

Comment: That's good!  Not the answer but the next closest fit I've seen

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Ice?

No one's more queer than me

> It can take a lot of forms (hence the strange) like iceberg, icecream, ice cube...

I can be a river, or a rain,

water pours from me

> It can be a river, since most of the rivers are originated from [Meltwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltwater). And it can also be rain considered as precipitacion (see [hail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail)). If we consider ice in the form of a glacier, then water pours from it.

Think I'm easy?

I'll burn your tongue.

> I can't find a noun or something referring to a particullar tongue burn caused by ice, so I can only trust the wisdom of [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090819145910AAuM3kD)

Comment: I like it but it's not the answer.